# Using feedparser with Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, feedparser, python-2.5

I am trying to parse an RSS feed with feedparser. The below code snipped is cut-short for brevity

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
import feedparser
print 'Content-Type: text/plain'

feed_url = 'http://parsethisurl'
feedinput = urlfetch.fetch(feed_url)

rss_parsed = feedparser.parse(feedinput.content)
......
#some logic here
.........

print "\n".join(episode_info) # printing out the desired output.
```

works fine on my python interpreter but when I add my application to gapp engine launcher and try to run it via `localhost:10000` it gives me the following error

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named feedparser 
      args = ('No module named feedparser',) 
      message = 'No module named feedparser'
```

`feedparser` module is already installed on my system.

```
>>> sys.version
'2.5.2 (r252:60911, Feb 21 2008, 13:11:45) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)]'
>>> import feedparser
>>>
```

I read some articles on stackoveflow and blogs that `feedparser` doesn't work directly on gapp engine. I followed the advice and used `urlfetch.fetch(feed_url)` but than also I am getting an error.

PS: PythonPath on gapp launcher is `C:\Python25\python.exe`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `feedparser` installed locally, so when you run your application on development server it works. But in order to use `feedparser` on production you need to include it in your project, because GAE do not provide this library for you.

You need to upload `feedparser` along with your project files. For this you can copy it into your application root directory and then deploy your application.